# How can I create a zip archive of a whole directory via terminal without hidden files?

Tags: command-line, zip

I have a project with lots of hidden folders / files in it. I want to create a zip-archive of it, but in the archive shouldn't be  any hidden folders / files. If files in a hidden folder are not hidden, they should also not be included.

I know that I can create a zip archive of a directory like this:

```
zip -r zipfile.zip directory
```

I also know that I can exclude files with the -x option, so I thought this might work:

```
zip -r zipfile.zip directory -x .*
```

It didn't work. All hidden directories were still in the zip-file.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This also excludes hidden files in unhidden directories:

```
find /full_path -path '*/.*' -prune -o -type f -print | zip ~/file.zip -@
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The command (`find community-chess/ -path '*/.*' -prune -o -type f -print | zip ~/community-chess.zip -@`) is longer than expected, but it works fine. Subdirectories are also included, so +1 and an accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 209):

First of all if you don't have installed zip install it first as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install zip
```

Then for simply creating a zip file:

```
zip -r compressed_filename.zip foldername
```

If you want to exclude hidden files:

```
find /folder_path -path '*/.*' -prune -o -type f -print | zip ~/compressed_filename.zip -@
```

**Excluding Files from a Zip Archive**
(taken from http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/30/how-to-exclude-files-from-a-zip-archive/)

> The basics of file exclusion when creating a zip archive are centered
>   around the `-x` flag, which is used to exclude files from the archive
>   that match a specific name or pattern. At it’s most basic, it will
>   look like this:
>
> ```
> zip archive.zip files -x "ExcludeMe"
> ```
>
> Meaning you could exclude a single file, say it’s named “Nothanks.jpg”
>
> ```
> zip archive.zip images/ -x "Nothanks.jpg"
> ```
>
> Let’s cover a few specific examples where this is useful.
>
> **Exclude .DS_Store Files from Zip Archives**
>
> This will prevent the typically invisible Mac metadata `.DS_Store`
>   files from being included in a zip archive, which are bundled in by
>   default:
>
> ```
> zip -r archivename.zip archivedirectory -x "*.DS_Store"
> ```
>
> If the directory includes subdirectories however, you’ll want to use
>   another variation of that command to exclude the the ds_store files
>   from subdirectories as well:
>
> ```
> zip -r archive.zip directory -x "*/\.DS_Store"
> ```
>
> Note: not all shells require the quotations for this command to work
>   properly, but in the bash shell (the default for OS X) you will need
>   to use the quotes for excluding with wildcards and patterns.
>
> **Exclude Specific File Types from a Zip Archive**
>
> With wildcards, you can also exclude all files of a certain type by
>   focusing on the extension. For example, this command will zip an
>   entire directory, minus any `.jpg` files:
>
> ```
> zip -r archive.zip directory -x "*.jpg"
> ```
>
> That could be modified for any specific file extension or pattern
>   matched in a file name.
>
> **Exclude the .git or .svn Directory from a Zip Archive**
>
> Zip a directory, minus `.git` and it’s contents:
>
> ```
> zip -r zipdir.zip directorytozip -x "*.git*"
> ```
>
> Zip a folder, without including the `.svn` directory:
>
> ```
> zip -r zipped.zip directory -x "*.svn*"
> ```
>
> **Exclude All Hidden Files from a Zip Archive**
>
> Since patterns and wildcards can be used, you could also exclude any
>   or all invisible files and folders that are made so by being prefixed
>   with a period, whether it’s a directory like `.svn` or an individual
>   file like `.bash_profile` or `.htaccess`.
>
> ```
> zip -r archivename.zip directorytozip -x "*.*"
> ```
>
> Or to exclude all invisible files from all subdirectories:
>
> ```
> zip -r archive.zip directory -x "*/\.*"
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help a fellow Ubuntu user. Please keep in mind that re-stating the accepted answer in a new answer just adds to the clutter and has a high probability of  being flagged for removal.

Comment: I don't understand why the question has more upvotes than this very thorough answer

Answer (score 62):

Add `"` to the `.*` (otherwise, your shell expands `.*` to the dot files in the current directory), and also exclude hidden files in subdirectories:

```
zip -r zipfile.zip . -x ".*" -x "*/.*"
```

This will result in files starting with a `.` not to be added into your zip file.

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  2 rinzwind rinzwind 4096 2011-08-28 00:15 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  2 rinzwind rinzwind 4096 2011-08-28 00:15 .tmp
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp$ zip -r zipfile.zip . -x .*
adding: .tmp/ (stored 0%)
adding: tmp/ (stored 0%)
rinzwind@discworld:~/tmp$ zip -r zipfile.zip . -x ".*" -x "*/.*"
updating: tmp/ (stored 0%)
```

Comment: I don't think your last statement is correct. `.*` would get expanded by the shell.

Comment: I think it is likely to be correct but I removed it (not sure about it) :)

Comment: this didn't work. The .svn-directories were added

Comment: @moose The exclude pattern matches the full path, not just the file base name, so you need to exclude `*/.*` as well as `.*` (`*/` matches any non-empty sequence of directories).

Comment: This runs without changing anything! Best answer.

Answer (score 12):

Example for excluding all folders begining with . :

```
tar cvpzf folder.tgz folder/ --exclude '.*'
```

Better compress but slower :

```
tar cvpjf folder.tar.bz2 folder/ --exclude '.*'
```

Answer (score 11):

This one includes all "." directories, subdirectories, and "." files or directories within directories...
Essentially the first answer but includes top level "." files.

```
find /full_path -path '*.*/.*' -prune -o -type f -print | zip ~/file.zip -@
```

Answer (score 9):

The correct method would be:

```
zip -r zipfile.zip directory -x directory/.*
```

Comment: @downvoter: What's wrong, this seems to be working for me.

Comment: Same problem as with [Rinzwind's original answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/58902) (now corrected): you aren't excluding subdirectories. And as Rinzwind noted, you need to quote the wildcards, otherwise the shell will expand them.

Answer (score 7):

While zipping dirs excluding some file extension:

```
$ cd /path/to/dir
$ zip -r dir.zip . -x "*.log" -x "*.cache"
```

Answer (score 7):

Without hidden folders and files in directory:

```
zip -r zipfile.zip directory/*
```

directory:

```
|── .git
│   
├── src
│   └── Work.file
├── .test
│   └── .file
└── test.file
```

```
$ zip -r zipfile.zip directory/*
adding: directory/src/ (stored 0%)
adding: directory/src/Work.file (stored 0%)
adding: directory/test.file (stored 0%)
```