# Shell scripting automation

Tags: automation

I just wanted to know that is there any process by which we can automate the process of fetching the server logs periodically by running some cron-jobs and saving the logs directly as a zipped file/normal text file into my local system. For the initial process I just want to have a java webapplication which will be configured with buttons. So what I plan to do is on click of a button I will get all the server logs related to the particular server saved as a zipped/normal text file in my local system. Can this actually be done ?

Comment: take a look in these tutorials:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up &&
https://www.shellscript.sh/ &&
https://askubuntu.com/questions/58889/how-can-i-create-a-zip-archive-of-a-whole-directory-via-terminal-without-hidden

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be done if you have access to those server.

I'd recommend to use clear bash script (maybe with different options) for this action instead of build Java application... Take a look on `scp` bash command